# Creating user in ubuntu from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

Using AWS (Amazon Web Services) I have created an Ubuntu 16.10 instance and I am able to login using a pem file like this: 
ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@52.16.73.14.54

After I am logged, I can see that I am able to execute: 
sudo su 
(with no password), however the file /etc/sudoers does NOT contain any reference to the user current user: ubuntu.

How can I create another user with exactly the same behavior (without touching the sudoers file) from terminal in a NON interactive way?

I tried: 
sudo useradd -m -c "adding a test user" -G sudo,adm -s /bin/bash testuser

But after I become "testuser" if I invoke:
sudo su
I have to provide a password. Which is exactly the way I want to avoid.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/504652/adding-nopasswd-in-etc-sudoers-doesnt-work is very likely to help you. Do `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/overrides` and type in `testuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`. Save file and try again.

Comment: Adding your test user to the `sudo` group should have worked. Did you confirm that your `useradd` command really added the new user to the `sudo` group in `/etc/group`?

Comment: And also group memberships don't update until the user has completely logged out and back in (all sessions - screens, X, whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without touching sudo, beacuse the ubuntu user is given passwordless access specifically.

```
$ for group in `groups ubuntu`; do sudo grep -r ^[[:space:]]*[^#]*$group[[:space:]] /etc/sudoers* ; done
/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users:ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users:ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
/etc/sudoers:%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But what you *can* do is create a new sudoers file without touching any *existing* files.  `sudo` is typically configured these days to read all the configurations in a directiory, usually `/etc/sudoers.d/`, preceisely so that one failing config doesn't effect the rest of sudo.

In your case, you might want to give an admin group sudoless access rather than your user.  Then you can add access in the future to other users without changing sudo config.